# get text inside quotes using regex

Tags: c#, .net, regex

I want to extract the data inside the quotes using regex

```
My Text is : boundary="s323sd2342423---"
```

Now i need to extract the value inside the double quotes without using substring.

I tried the following but didnt help.

```
String pattern = @"boundary=""(?<value>[^""]*";
Match m = Regex.Match(rawMessage, pattern);
while (m.Success)
{
    boundaryString = m.Groups["value"].Value;
    m = m.NextMatch();
}
```

Comment: You forgot closing parenthesis of your named group and closing quotes for the "attribute"

Comment: Well, Im not so good at regex. :) Thanks..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to close opening bracket of a group

```
String pattern = @"boundary=""(?<value>[^""]*)";
```

now if you go with

```
Console.WriteLine(m.Groups["value"].Value);
```

will print:

```
s323sd2342423---
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this pattern and it will work.

```
String pattern = @"boundary=\""(?<value>.+?)\""";
```

Answer (score 1):

With the following Regex you'll get what you want without any grouping

```
(?<=boundary=")[^"]+(?=")
```

Code to get the the quoted text:

```
string txt = "boundary=\"s323sd2342423---\"";
string quotedTxt = Regex.Match(txt, @"(?<=boundary="")[^""]+(?="")").Value;
```

Answer (score 0):

As per you details:

> I want to extract the data inside the quotes using regex

Why not you just use this pattern:

```
"(?<value>[^"]+)"
```